# Clojure - Filter keys from a map

Tags: clojure

Let's assume I have a hashmap and I want to filter out entry by keys provided in a given vector. For example assuming I have 
 1. map: {:k1 "v1" :k2 "v2" :k3 "v3"}
 2. list: [:k2 :k4]

and I want to be left with k1, k3

My current solution is:

```
(defn rr
  "remove key that are in set from the map"
  [m1 s]
  (loop [mm m1 ss s]
    (if (first ss)
      (recur (dissoc mm (first ss)) (rest ss))
      mm)))
```

Wonder do you prettier solution?

Comment: `(apply dissoc {:k1 "v1" :k2 "v2" :k3 "v3"} [:k2 :k4])` , since `dissoc` can take multiple keys to remove, it can operate on keys collection with `apply`, or else you can use `reduce` the same way: `(reduce dissoc {:k1 "v1" :k2 "v2" :k3 "v3"} [:k2 :k4])`

Comment: If only your comment was an answer, @leetwinski. It could be selected as the right answer. :-)

Comment: @leetwinski Can you please write your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(apply dissoc {:k1 "v1" :k2 "v2" :k3 "v3"} [:k2 :k4])`

Since dissoc can take multiple keys to remove, it can operate on keys collection with apply, or else you can use reduce the same way:

`(reduce dissoc {:k1 "v1" :k2 "v2" :k3 "v3"} [:k2 :k4])`

so your function `rr` could be:

`(def dissoc-keyset (partial apply dissoc))`

Comment: And be sure to remember the inverse function `select-keys`:  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/select-keys